# Unable to see vsts work items in code lens: Unable to determine the team project collection

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, codelens

I'm getting following error:

[image: Unable to determine the team project collection. Please connect to the appropriate team collection and try again]

I've double checked that I added my work account to visual studio, which I use also for VSTS access:

[image: vs accounts]

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Are you connected to your VSTS instance in the Team Explorer?

Comment: What's the detail version of VS 2017? Try to connect to VSTS in team explorer, then open the solution. On the other hand, try to clear client cache (`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[version]`)

Comment: When I connect to VSTS in Team Explorer (Menu -> Team -> Manage Connection), it closes the solution. I guess it connected me to TFVC repository which I accidentally created and I'm not able to delete it. I had to delete this connection and create new. It is quite ununtuitive though, especially since there was no settings for VSTS in Team Explorer. Just for git (Team Explorer -> Home -> Settings)

Comment: You connected to the local git repository, so there no settings for VSTS. Regarding TFVC issue: 1. Remove the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution ... EndGlobalSection` code from solution file 2. remove `<SccXXX>...</SccXXX> (e.g. SccProjectName)` from project file. 3. Remove `.vspscc` files. Connect to VSTS git repository: 1. Open Team explorer=>Connection window=>Manage Connections=>Connect to team project=>Select a git repository in a team project=>Click Connect

Comment: What's the result after trying with this way?

Comment: I got it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You connected to the local git repository, so there no settings for VSTS.

Regarding TFVC issue:

1. Remove the GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution ... EndGlobalSection code from solution file
2. remove ... (e.g. SccProjectName) from project file.
3. Remove .vspscc files. Connect to VSTS git repository: 1. Open Team explorer=>Connection window=>Manage Connections=>Connect to team project=>Select a git repository in a team project=>Click Connect